Convergence at $+ \infty$ of a limit of a stochastic process
Let $X_n(t)$ be a stochastic process living in $D(0,+\infty)$, the space of cadlag function on the positive real numbers.
Let's assume that, as $X_n(t)$ converges in distribution for the Skorokhod distance $d$  to some limiting deterministic process $x(t)$ :  $$X_n(t) \underset{n \to \infty}{\to} x(t)$$
If I know that $X_n(t) \underset{t \to \infty}{\to} \ell_n $ almost surely for all $n$, where $\ell_n$ is a random variable, does this imply that the limiting process $x(t)$ has a limit at $t= + \infty$ ?

If the convergence is uniform in $n$ and $\ell_n \underset{t \to \infty}{\to} \ell$ for some constant $\ell$, this would yield the result, but this cannot be necessary.
Are there known counterexamples of sequences of stochastic processes that have a limit at $t = +\infty$ but whose limiting processes don't ?
